# Using a text checkpoint file in Docker - how can this file be modified?

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image that consists of a python program. The program makes use of a text checkpoint file to record a checkpoint between runs. If I run this program in a Docker container, the checkpoint file gets updated after the run, but this does not persist between runs.

To resolve this I can make use of a volume. I would like to set this checkpoint to various values for testing purposes. Is the only way to do this to rebuild the image with each different checkpoint value (my build is quite slow)? I do not have root access on the host, so editing the file in the volume location directly is not possible.

Comment: If you can command a docker daemon running as root, you effectively have root on the host—just bind-mount `/` to a container of your choice and modify whatever you like.

Comment: If you need to edit the file, you can use a bind-mount instead of a named volume.  In any case, if the checkpoint file is stored outside the container, you shouldn't normally need to rebuild the image to re-run the container.

Comment: This is a setup where I have a designated user that can command the docker daemon, however I do not have root access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount the volume to *another* container, which will be, say, base Ubuntu image with shell and set the content there.

Comment: This is the approach I used. I didn't investigate settng the checkpoint in this way, but I at least could read the checkpoint file. One thing that was important to do was to not have the checkpoint file in my image, but rather to have the code create it if it did not exist. If I have the checkpoint file in that location, it would always be used and it looked like that file would 'overwrite' the one that was saved in the volume.